# Android 4.2 - Bad text render - Text flickers and gets cut

Tags: android, android-fragments, mobile, rendering, render

We have an native Android application developed in Java and Android Studio.
We started observing a phenomenon which seems to be related with rendering (but might not?).

In the photo bellow the table is rendered correctly:

[image: First Render OK]

When ticking one of the checkboxes to select a row, the fields show only the first letter:

[image: Render Problem]

Setting focus to one of the textboxes, or turning the tablet (horizontal / vertical) temporarily fixes the issue, and the table is rendered correctly.
It doesn't matter at which point you click the checkboxes, the problem shows again.

We ran the app on different devices:

- Samsung S4 mini, Android 4.4.2 (not showing error)
- Lenovo Tablet,   Android 4.4.2 (not showing error)
- Samsung S4,      Android 4.2.2 (showing the error)
- Winmate tablet,  Android 4.2.2 (showing the error)

What can this be?
Any advice on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Shy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I discover that RowLayout has this bug on some Android versions (I saw this bug on Android 4.2 version but not on 4.4 versions). Try changing RowLayout for LinearLayout, that'll do the trick.